# How to set woocommerce order total to calculate ONLY shipping costs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce as a platform for booking products for delivery, People pay only for the shipping costs but not for the products.

How do I get the total amount to reflect ONLY the shipping costs and not the product prices?

I know I can set the individual product price to zero but I prefer to leave the prices there so that people can sort the items by price. Hopefully it's just a simple hack.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a shipping rule and assigns this rule to product

Comment: Thanks but then the product prices will still be calculated won't they at checkout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add shipping role and assign them to all.
Or create a function that remove the product cost from the total in function.php file.

This might help:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

    function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
        $custom_price = $shipping; // Add the shipping cost
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
           $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hemel. Not sure how the shipping role can be used though. The function bit will probably work but I'm not quite sure how to do that in actual code.

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly Hemel. A million thanks. You are a champion. :) *thumbs up

Comment: I wonder if a woocommerce update has changed the variable name, somehow it's not working anymore. ;(

Comment: You have to put it in the function again or create a child theme which don't get updated. Or the code will replace after every update.